Find $\varphi$,$\psi$ such that $\psi f \varphi^{-1}(\zeta)=\zeta^n$
Premise: We define a local map in $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, a bianalytic homeomorphism $\varphi$ defined in a neighborhood of $z_0$ such that $\varphi(z_0) = 0$.
Let $f$ be an analytic function defined in a $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ surrounding. Then there exists an analytic local map $\varphi$ around $z_0$, a $\psi$ around $f\left(z_0\right) and$ a positive integer $n$ such that
$$
\psi f \varphi^{-1}(\zeta)=\zeta^n .
$$
I give you an example from my teacher's notes:
Let $f=z-z \cos z$ and $z_0=0$, then
$$
f(z)=z^3\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2 n!} z^{2 n-2}\right) .
$$
Letting
$$
\begin{aligned}
\varphi(\zeta) & =\sqrt[3]{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2 n!} \zeta^{2 n-2}} \\
\psi(w) & =w-f(z_0)=w,
\end{aligned}
$$
one obtains:
$$
\psi f \varphi^{-1}(\zeta)=\zeta^3
$$
First question: is this example consistent with the premise?
Second question:
Let $f:{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow {\mathbb{C}}$ the analytic application defined by
$$
f(z)=1+\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{z^3} .
$$
Find a map $\phi$ around -1 and a $\psi$ around $f(-1)$, such that $\psi f \phi^{-1}(\zeta)=\zeta^n$ for some $n>0$.
I found that the application is of the form $\zeta \longmapsto \zeta^2 $ in $z=-1$, which is a ramification point. But how to find $\phi$ and $\psi$? Thanks

Just to clarify: What do you mean by "consistent with premise"? As for second question, I think just follow the proof about the local behavior of analytic mapping will give you $\phi$ or $\psi$. Since you are working with holomorphic map $f$ over $\mathbb{C}$, $\psi$ can be chosen to be just translation. You can find detail in, for example, chapter 7 of Complex made simple by David Ulrich.

compare Bottcher's theorem, (1904)  where $0$ is superattracting, that is $f(z) = a_n z^n + a_{n+1}  z^{n+1}+ ...$   with $n \geq 2$   and $a_n \neq 0.$  Then, near the origin, there is a local holomorphic change of coordinate $\phi$  such that $\phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1} ; :  ; w \mapsto w^n$  This is Theorem 6.7 in Milnor's book
